# jQuery royalSlider function not firing in IE8 or IE7

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, syntax, internet-explorer-8

Here's the page I'm having trouble with:
http://www.jonathanadler.com/presstest3.php

[RoyalSlider](http://dimsemenov.com/plugins/royal-slider/) is working fine in all browsers except IE8 and IE7 (and the plugin is supposed to support those browsers). **embedTumblr** is working fine, as is **removeClass**, but the **royalSlider** function isn't firing.

Here's my script on the page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#posts_container').embedTumblr('http://api.tumblr.com/v2/blog/japress.tumblr.com/posts?api_key=k9xgGA3H3LY3WFHgXMosOExTgQFSnhdGZCdrCdGJSgGSnLbg34');
    });
    $(window).load(function() {
        $('#posts_container').removeClass('hide');
        $('.royalSlider').royalSlider({
            arrowsNav: false,
            autoScaleSlider: false,
            imageAlignCenter: false,
            addActiveClass: true,
            controlNavigation: 'none',
            fadeinLoadedSlide: false,
            globalCaption: true,
            globalCaptionInside: true,
            imageScaleMode: 'fit',
            keyboardNavEnabled: true,
            visibleNearby: {
                enabled: true,
                centerArea: 0.4,
                center: true,
                breakpoint: 0,
                navigateByCenterClick: true
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

I'm relatively new to javascript/jquery so I'm guessing it's probably a syntax issue or something similar. Any help you could give would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Some suggestions:

(1) Try using a  different doctype as the one you're using may cause issues.

Either:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

or

```
<!doctype html> (If you want to switch to HTML5 - recommended)
```

(2) Run your site through an HTML and CSS validatior as you have a large amount of errors.

- http://validator.w3.org/
- http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/

(3) I think you'd be as well having your slider JS code inside the document ready block too. Unless there was a good reason for using the window load inside that?

(4) You're running an older version of jQuery. Consider updating that to the latest release.

Comment: When I try moving the JS that's currently in window.load into the document.ready block, it breaks in every browser (in the same way as in IE8… everything but .royalSlider fires). I don't know if that helps diagnose the problem. As for your other suggestions, I'm wary of changing things globally on the site in case it breaks other functions, but I'll try those once I'm sure my page-specific code isn't the problem. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

We can see lot of JS requests here:

[image: JS requests]

And 2 files for the JQuery library:

http://www.jonathanadler.com/skin1/jquery-1.8.0.min.js
http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js

So let me think about a JS conflict.

Comment: We had our developers look into it and they removed the Google 1.7.1 version, but it's still not firing. I wouldn't be surprised if it were a JS conflict of some sort though; we've got a lot going on…

Comment: Using boilerplate (framework) can be a good way to prevent JS conflict.